# How to make a variable accessible through out the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I have a variable assigned like this:

`cryptsy = Cryptsy::API::Client.new(key, secret)`

How can I make this variable accessible through out the application?

Currently its in the Application controller, but I am using GRAPE gem to create a simple api. I need to be able to access the variable in /app/api/v1/bla.rb and other files in the v1 folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an initializer to instantiate on application load.  In config/application.rb do something like

```
require 'cryptsy/api'

module YourApp 
  Cryptsy = Cryptsy::API::Client.new(key, secret)
  ...
end
```

This will give you a universally accessible instance of this object.

Comment: I got an error saying `Unidentified local variable or method`. I pretty much took your code, replaced YourApp with `TheCryptoApi` which is the name of my rails project and stuck it in application.rb. I might have done something wrong (sorry im just getting started with rails).

Comment: Where are you getting Cryptsy from?  Is it a gem?

Comment: Well, yes. Cryptsy is a online exchange for altcoins. http://cryptsy.com Someone took the API and made it a gem. https://rubygems.org/gems/cryptsy-api https://github.com/nbarthel/cryptsy-api

Comment: updated my answer, from the docs you need to require the lib.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: I still get this error: `undefined local variable or method 'cryptsy' for V1::Btc:Class (NameError)`. Here is a gist with my code for my application.rb file. https://gist.github.com/nahtnam/8c339d07d6ef1fce6daa

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a class in lib and adding it there. Make sure to add lib to autoload path in config/application.rb

```
class Cryptsy
  def self.client
    @cryptsy ||= Cryptsy::API::Client.new(key, secret)
  end
end
```

And whereever you want to use it, you can call

```
Cryptsy.client
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following code to the file `app_root/config/initializers/cryptsy.rb`

```
require 'cryptsy-api' # this line might be needed
$cryptsy = Cryptsy::API::Client.new(key, secret)
```

then you can access `$cryptsy` through out the app.

Comment: It somewhat works. When I make a call, it returns the number and NIL. My api is now returning NIL instead of the number.

Comment: Could you specify more details about each case?